# Double Login PHP System

Tags: php, session, authentication, multiple-login

I have a question regarding PHP login systems. Is it possible to have a login system within another login system.

Here's an example: I login to a site and PHP creates the session. I then want to access another page with some higher-secure content so I ask the user to re-type their username/password to gain access to that page.

Can this be done using different sessions or the same session? it would be great if the original session is not ended so once the user finishes on the page with the higher-secure content they can continue to use the previous pages.

Hope this makes sense, any information which could possibly point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Sure it is possible. Just keep what kind of authentication user already have performed.

Like:

```
$_SESSION['auth_type'] = 'first one'; // when user logged in first time
$_SESSION['auth_type'] = 'more secured one'; // when user logged in second time time
```

After that you can check what kind of authentication user have had:

```
if ($_SESSION['auth_type'] == 'first one') {
    // ask for second auth here
}
```

Etc...

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using the same session.

Just do something like this once they have logged into the second area.

```
$_SESSION['secondArea'] = TRUE;
```

You can `unset()` that when they log out of the second area.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like your user to log in once more *every time* they view the content, you could use a POST login form, and then before displaying the data on the page, check the POSTed username and password before displaying the content.

e.g. (in pseudocode)

```
if request is a POST and username and password are valid:
    display content
else:
    display login form
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same session - identified by the same cookie on his side. But just set and check different session variables to represent the various login statuses: `$_SESSION['hasUserAccess']` and `$_SESSION['hasAdminAccess']`.

Or perhaps: `$_SESSION['accessStatus']` which can have values like `'public'`, `'user'`, `'admin'`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to secure it even more, I would recommend using MD5 for session.

```
$_SESSION['userAuth'] = 'here-md5-hash';
```

encrypt the MD5 and store it(for username only) and then save it.
So your server knows the decryption.

This makes it very hard someone to intercept it.